# How to prepare interactions of categorical variables in scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, interaction, python, scikit-learn

**What is the best way to prepare interactions of categorical features before fitting with scikit-learn?**

With `statsmodels` I could conveniently say in R-style `smf.ols(formula = 'depvar ~ C(var1)*C(var2)', data=df).fit()` (same in Stata with `regress depvar i.var1##i.var2`).

Can `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` (in v0.15, currently dev) be used with categorical variables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed you can use Patsy with scikit-learn to obtain the same results you would obtain with R, or with the formula notation in stats models. See code below:

```
from patsy import dmatrices

# create dummy variables, and their interactions
y, X = dmatrices('depvar ~ C(var1)*C(var2)', df, return_type="dataframe")
# flatten y into a 1-D array so scikit-learn can understand it
y = np.ravel(y)
```

you can now use any model implemented in scikit-learn with the usual notations having X as independent variables, and y as dependent one.

Comment: what if we want to have an empty LHS? (`~var1*var2` is perfectly fine in R for constructing the RHS matrix)

Comment: (you should mention `dmatrix`)

Answer (score 10):

Use [Patsy](http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Patsy is one of my favourite Python libraries: it does one thing, and only one thing, really really well.